# using v-if and v-else for dynamically change the component in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to show some tasks (like to-do tasks) and the taskList without navigating between these components. (Both Task and TaskList are components). But I couldn't find a proper way to load one component or the other one dynamically. As you can guess, when the user clicked on an item in the list he/she will see the details in the same main component.

In main view component, I did something like that

```html
<template>
<TabView ...>
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto, *">
        <SegmentedBar row="0" col="0">
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Meine Aufträge" />
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Auftragspool" />
        </SegmentedBar>

        <GridLayout row="1">
            <component v-for="component in componentsArray"  
            v-show="component === currentComponent" 
           :is="component" v-bind:key="component" 
           @changeComponent="changeValue" />

        </GridLayout>
</TabView>

<script>
    //...
    data() { //...
            return {
                currentComponent: "ServiceOrderList",
                componentsArray: ["ServiceOrderList", "TaskDetails"]
            };
        },
        methods: {
            changeValue(payload) {
                this.payload = payload
                this.currentComponent = "TaskDetails"
            }
</script>
  // another TabViews
</template>
```

This one is working (when I put static string in TaskDetails), but I can't send the payload to the TaskDetails,

but this approach didn't worked

```html
<v-template if="currentComponent==='ServiceOrderList'">
                       <ServiceOrderList/>
                     </v-template>


                     <v-template if="currentComponent==='TaskDetails'">
                       <TaskDetails :data="this.payload"/>
                     </v-template>
```

So what other ways I can try to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample?

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this sort of thing I pass the component in the changeValue like changeValue(component). Was payload what you expected when you console logged it out?

Also, this bit in your sudo code confuses me a little too

```
</script>
  // another TabViews
</template>
```

this isn't how you're writing components right? My understanding of single file components was that they have one template and one script tag?

Comment: Yes, this part is mistaken written or wrong C/P, TabViews are of course between the <Template> tags.

Comment: And yes there is no problem with console.log of payload, I think in nativescript-vue we can't use if and else with Template tags.
I put the if and else to my component and it worked, like `<TaskDetails if="logic here">`

Comment: @senko so I think using the component tag to switch between components doesn't work after playing around with it for awhile (NS playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vnCqFH&v=3))

Comment: what I've had success with in the past is in a v-for loop dynamically registering different components based on the data that was being passed. I guess that's why I thought what you were trying to achieve would work, but yeah I can't get it working.